# how to detect that the app is previously purchased by user

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, in-app-purchase

I recently changed my paid app model to in-app purchase model, its easy to detect that the users who already purchased the app will not get the in-app purchase options when they update the app.

But the problem if these users delete the app and download again or they download in new device, then how to detect that the app is previously purchased.

I am **not** talking about in-app purchase or restore purchase. I want to detect user who purchased app from app store **not** from in-app purchase.

Comment: You can't determine, because it is the purchase which user did before downloading app, though you might be having database of users, so you can determine as per dates before you made your app free, those users would have purchased the app.

Comment: Yup, if You have something like first app run timestamp or something similar, You can make that deduction.

Comment: Did you manage to find a solution to this?